# Google Apps Script: conditional email send

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a script for Google Sheets that will send an email when the field B2="Yes" in the sheet "Output." I've got it running now without errors, but it emails *every time* I run the script, regardless of what the value of B1 is.

I think the problem is due to my ignorant attempt to nest a function (send email) inside of another function (if/then). I thought I had both functions working correctly, before I combined them. Can you help set me straight?

```html
function contionalSender() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output");
  var currentValue = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  if (currentValue = ("'Yes'")) {
  var emailsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Address");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = emailsheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1;
  var dataRange = emailsheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  
    var message = row[1];       
    var subject = "";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  
}
  }
}
```

Comment: You have typo in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your code

```
if (currentValue = ("'Yes'"))
```

Should be

```
if (currentValue == ("'Yes'"))
```